# Creating a difference of the data frame with 1 col in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and trying to replicate things in python that are done in excel.

I want to take difference of the col(A,B,C) with the mean(fixed)

```
    Unnamed:0   A   B   C   mean    Mean diffA
0   2020-08-28  1   6   11  6.0 -5.0
1   2020-08-29  2   7   12  7.0 -5.0
2   2020-08-30  3   8   13  8.0 -5.0
3   2020-08-31  4   9   14  9.0 -5.0
4   2020-09-01  5   10  15  10.0    -5.0
```

1 way is to manually put in the col name and find the difference, but is there any other less manual way?

```
new_df['Mean diffA']=new_df['A']-new_df['mean']
```

Comment: Would be great to mention which library you use

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the mean from a range of columns:

```
diffs = new_df.loc[:, 'A':'C'].subtract(new_df['mean'], axis=0)
```

Then combine the differences and the original DataFrame:

```
new_df.join(diffs, rsuffix='_mean')
```

Comment: thank you, but if i have large set of data, do i still need to enter('A':'C')?, is there a way of using index ing to specify the column

Comment: Yes, you can use indexes with .iloc

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to do this. I tried the following and it worked.

```
import pandas as pd

dt = {'START DATE':['2020-08-28','2020-08-29','2020-08-30',
                      '2020-08-31','2020-09-01'],
      'A':[1,2,3,4,5],
      'B':[6,7,8,9,10],
      'C':[11,12,13,14,15]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dt)

df['Mean'] = df.loc[:,'A':'C'].mean(axis=1)

df[['dA','dB','dC']] = df.loc[:, 'A':'C'].subtract(df['Mean'], axis=0)

print(df)
```

OR you can try and do something like this as well

```
df[['dA','dB','dC']] = df.loc[:,'A':'C'] - df[['Mean','Mean','Mean']].values

print(df)
```

Both of these will provide the same output:

```
   START DATE  A   B   C  Mean   dA   dB   dC
0  2020-08-28  1   6  11   6.0 -5.0  0.0  5.0
1  2020-08-29  2   7  12   7.0 -5.0  0.0  5.0
2  2020-08-30  3   8  13   8.0 -5.0  0.0  5.0
3  2020-08-31  4   9  14   9.0 -5.0  0.0  5.0
4  2020-09-01  5  10  15  10.0 -5.0  0.0  5.0
```

The second option is not a good way to use it. Pandas provides you [subtract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) function. Use this.